# Why I get No apply function found for scala.Enumeration.Value for enum field?

Tags: scala, enums, playframework, slick

I have defined my enumeration field:

```
object ContractTypeEnum extends Enumeration {
  type ContractTypeEnum = Value
  val Key1 = Value("key1")
  val Key2 = Value("key2")
}
```

And defined its mapping in scala `Postgres`:

```
trait  EnumImplicit {
  implicit val ContractTypeEnumMapper = PostgresDriver.createEnumJdbcType("contract_type", ContractTypeEnum)
}
```

In my case class for my table I have defined the column as:

```
contractType: Option[ContractTypeEnum.ContractTypeEnum]
```

And created its `Implicit Formatter` like below:

```
implicit val contractTypeFormat = new Format[ContractTypeEnum.ContractTypeEnum] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(ContractTypeEnum.withName(json.as[String]))
    def writes(myEnum: ContractTypeEnum.ContractTypeEnum) = JsString(myEnum.toString)
  }
```

What I get is the below error:

```
Error:(61, 92) No apply function found for scala.Enumeration.Value
    implicit val optionFormat: Format[ContractTypeEnum] = Format.optionWithNull(Json.format[ContractTypeEnum])
```

And the below reader/writer is also written:

```
object ContractJsonModel {
  implicit val ContractJsonModelFormat = {
    implicit val optionFormat: Format[ContractTypeEnum] = Format.optionWithNull(Json.format[ContractTypeEnum])
    Jsonx.formatCaseClass[ContractJsonModel]
  }
}
```

What is the error and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works as expected:

```
object ContractTypeEnum extends Enumeration {
  type ContractTypeEnum = Value
  val Key1 = Value("key1")
  val Key2 = Value("key2")

  implicit val readsMyEnum = Reads.enumNameReads(ContractTypeEnum)
  implicit val writesMyEnum = Writes.enumNameWrites

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are special format method in Json for enumerations `Json.formatEnum`. You can write like that:

```
implicit val optionFormat: Format[Option[ContractTypeEnum]] = Format.optionWithNull(Json.formatEnum(ContractTypeEnum))
```

Also, you should set the type of `optionFormat` as `Format[Option[ContractTypeEnum]]`, not `Format[ContractTypeEnum]`

Or you can replace `format` with `reads` and `writes` like that

```
    implicit val optionReads: Reads[Option[ContractTypeEnum]] = Reads.optionWithNull(Reads.enumNameReads(ContractTypeEnum))
    implicit val optionWrites: Writes[Option[ContractTypeEnum]] = Writes.optionWithNull(Writes.enumNameWrites[ContractTypeEnum.type])
```

Comment: `formatEnum` does not exist in json library. I could not find this function.

Comment: it is strange. Maybe there not exits that method in your version of play. So you can define reads and writes separately. `Format` is just a union of reads and writes. I edited my answer and put the version of defining of reads and writes at the end of my answer

Comment: Maybe it is possible to omit writes because there exist implicit writes for `enumeration`. So only `reads` is enough.